# Refactoring React to Typescript causes error Property 'readOnly' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm refactoring an application with Typescript. Everthing's going well except for this simple component. I'm using `Input` from `material-ui`.

```
import {Input} from "material-ui";

class Cp extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render = () => <Input readOnly/>          
}
```

Typescript compiler complains about `readOnly` property but it was working well in JavaScript.

```
TS2559: Type '{ readOnly: true; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

However I can see the property `readOnly` in the interface `HTMLInputElement` extended by the props of the `Input` element.

How to bypass this error ?

Answer (score 3):

readOnly is not props for Input component.
Have you try this way?

`<Input inputProps={{ readOnly: true }} />`